# how can I use a selector of a library component?

Tags: angular, typescript, templates, module, components

I made a library that I'm importing into my app through a npm link. The library is made by a module,which contains component A with a selector named app-sqv.
In my app I have component B and template B. In template B I would like to use the selector.

This of course is possible with an internal component, but here I'm not able to do it, maybe because with an external library there is something I'm not considering?
I have imported component A into component B with the classic import statement. I also can use the function in that component, so I'm excluding importing errors.

ModuleA.ts:

```
import { NgModule, } from '@angular/core';
import { AppSqvComponent } from './app-sqv.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    exports: [AppSqvComponent],
    declarations: [AppSqvComponent],
    providers: [],
})
export class EmptyTextModule { }
```

ComponentA.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector:    'app-sqv',
    templateUrl: './app-sqv.component.html',
    providers:  []
})

export class AppSqvComponent { .. }
```

ModuleB.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

ComponentB.ts

```
import {AppSqvComponent} from 'node_modules/viewseq';
```

TemplateB.html

```
<div>
  <h1>
    Testing Library!
  </h1>
  <app-sqv></app-sqv>
</div>
```

The error state that component B can't recognize the selector app-sqv.

Comment: You need to add the module in which `ComponentA` was _declared/exported_ into the _imports_ array of the module in which the component that consumes `ComponentA` is declared. In your case, `EmptyTextModule` should be added to the root module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `export` component A in **public_api.ts** of your libary.

```
export * from './lib/ComponentA/component-A.component';
```

and `import` your library module in app.module:

`import { MyLibraryModule } from 'my-library';`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    MyLibraryModule 
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't explain that I had already exported component A in public_api.ts of my library.
I've tried also importing the module as you say in app.module, but it can't recognize it...
I don't understand why it can't, since I'm able to import it in ComponentB and actually using it's functions...

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz?

Comment: Problem solved: 
I've created a new library from scratch using "ng generate library", just to start fresh and copied my old component code.
Then in my ts.config.json I had to set "module": "esnext", and "target": "es2015".
Before I was using es5.
I don't fully understand, but I think it was a problem during compilation, maybe I was using some old syntax not compatible with my settings in the config...
Thank you for your help anyway!!!